# Cosa vuol dire "venirne fuori" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Ma come poteva cavarsela con una ragazzina di dodici anni? Avrebbero finito per arrestarlo e mettere lei al riformatorio. Vita, le disse, sfiorandole il viso con le mani, ti voglio bene anch’io. Sei la mia ragazza. Ti giuro che torno. Lei fissò con le labbra tremanti il lembo della mutanda che gli spuntava dalla tasca della giacca. Stava andando via. Con tutto quello che aveva. E senza di lei. Le scoppiava il cuore. Diamante si precipitò verso le scale. Un minuto di piú, e non sarebbe mai partito. Mentre scendeva, si ricordò di aver dimenticato il sussidiario. La sua unica arma, per **venirne fuori** senza scorciatoie. Ma non c’era tempo per tornare indietro.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "venirne fuori" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "fuori" di parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a vedere a quale accezione possa corrispondere. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Venirne fuori** nel linguaggio corrente si riferisce allo sfuggire ad una situazione difficile o pericolosa.

Può essere vista come una contrazione di *venire fuori dai guai* o *venire fuori dal pericolo*.

L'immagine figurata è quella di essere immersi nel problema, per cui *venirne fuori* ha il significato di *emergere* e *sfuggire*.

Answer (score 4):

***[Venirne fuori](https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/V/venire.html)***:

> riuscire a superare una situazione particolarmente grave, complessa o dolorosa, specialmente  senza gravi danni: *era coinvolto in uno scandalo: gli è stato difficile venirne fuori*.

(Hoepli)